# Crash when compiling null, at character offset null - Flutter and Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm new to flutter and dart and I am trying to make a clone of instagram for studying purposes, but I am getting the error below.

Could you help me identify where the code is incorrect?

The output message error is in the end.

I tried google, and refactor the code ir order to apply the Null Safe, but in reality I don't know where exactly is the wrong code.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter/responsive/mobile_screen_layout.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter/responsive/responsive_layout_screen.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter/responsive/web_screen_layout.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter/utils/colors.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Instagram Clone',
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
      ),
      home: ResponsiveLayout(
        webScreenLayout: WebScreenLayout(),
        mobileScreenLayout: MobileScreenLayout(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**mobile_screen_layout.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MobileScreenLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const MobileScreenLayout({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('This is mobile'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**responsive_layout_screen.dart**

In the IF ELSE below, i tried put a verification in some ways, to verify is the value is zero or null, but didn't work. I also tried to put ? in the end of contrainsts.maxWidth because I saw in my researchs that this avoids the null value, but didn't work either.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter/responsive/web_screen_layout.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter/utils/dimensions.dart';

class ResponsiveLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget webScreenLayout;
  final Widget mobileScreenLayout;

  const ResponsiveLayout({
    super.key,
    required this.webScreenLayout,
    required this.mobileScreenLayout,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        if (constraints.maxWidth > webScreenSize) {
          return webScreenLayout;
        }
        return mobileScreenLayout;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**web_screen_layout.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WebScreenLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const WebScreenLayout({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('This is web'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**colors.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const mobileBackgroundColor = Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1);
const webBackgroundColor = Color.fromRGBO(18, 18, 18, 1);
const mobileSearchColor = Color.fromRGBO(38, 38, 38, 1);
const blueColor = Color.fromRGBO(0, 149, 246, 1);
const primaryColor = Colors.white;
const secondaryColor = Colors.grey;
```

**dimensions.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:instagram_flutter/responsive/web_screen_layout.dart';

const webScreenSize = 600;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[Running] dart "c:\Development\instagram_flutter\lib\main.dart"
Crash when compiling null,
at character offset null:
Null check operator used on a null value
#0      InferableTypeBuilderMixin.type (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/type_builder.dart:392:29)
#1      InferableTypeBuilder.inferType (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/omitted_type_builder.dart:155:12)
#2      SourceLoader.performTopLevelInference (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:2358:19)
#3      KernelTarget.buildOutlines.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:532:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _buildInternal (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:139:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      generateKernel.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:47:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      generateKernel (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:46:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      kernelForModule (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/kernel_generator.dart:100:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     SingleShotCompilerWrapper.compileInternal (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:412:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     Compiler.compile.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:221:45)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     _processLoadRequest (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:914:37)
<asynchronous suspension>


#0      InferableTypeBuilderMixin.type (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/type_builder.dart:392:29)
#1      InferableTypeBuilder.inferType (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/omitted_type_builder.dart:155:12)
#2      SourceLoader.performTopLevelInference (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:2358:19)
#3      KernelTarget.buildOutlines.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:532:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _buildInternal (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:139:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      generateKernel.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:47:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      generateKernel (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:46:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      kernelForModule (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/kernel_generator.dart:100:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     SingleShotCompilerWrapper.compileInternal (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:412:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     Compiler.compile.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:221:45)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     _processLoadRequest (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:914:37)
<asynchronous suspension>


[Done] exited with code=252 in 5.039 seconds
```

Comment: you;ve pasted same data on `dimensions` as color

Comment: @YeasinSheikh sorry, already corrected.

Comment: try below answer and let me know if it solves the issue

Comment: I think there is `!` sign was used on `null` variable.

Answer (score 2):

After 3 days of searching I was able to fix the problem, just through deleting this [Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikfgf.jpg), if you don't have this extension but  the problem persists, then the problem is definitely one extension, try disabling it one by one and reload vscode until you find it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is from `ResponsiveLayout`

```dart
if (constraints.maxWidth > webScreenSize?) { //here
  return webScreenLayout;
}
```

remove `?` and do like

```dart
if (constraints.maxWidth > webScreenSize) {  
  return webScreenLayout;
}
```

Comment: Same error. Updated the code.

Comment: Can you try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: I executed the following commands, same error

flutter clean
flutter packages get
flutter upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Disable coderunner extension and run **flutter upgrade** and also if is it doesn't work, run **flutter clean** and then  **flutter pub get** in terminal, it works for me hope for you too

Answer (score 0):

Disable coderunner extension and restart your workspace/vs code. It works for me hope for you too.